# REACT NODE JS AND MYSQL

Tags: mysql, reactjs, api, mongoose

i have this code i did with mongoose that im trying to implement on mysql.
this code gets all information from ONLINE API and inserts it into mongoose database.
anyone has any idea how would this code work with React, Node and MYSQL?

```
import mongoose, { mongo } from 'mongoose';

mongoose.connect("mongodb://127.0.0.1:27017/highscore");

const postSchema = new mongoose.Schema({

    position: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    id: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },
    score: {
        type: Number,
        required: true
    },

});

const Post = mongoose.model('Players', postSchema);

async function getPosts() {
    const getPlayers = await fetch("http://localhost:3008/api/highscore/players");
    const response = await getPlayers.json();
    for( let i = 0;i < response.players.length; i++){

const post = new Post({
    position: response.players[i]['position'],
    id: response.players[i]['id'],
    score: response.players[i]['score'],
});
post.save();


    }

}
```

***WHAT I BEEN THINKING***
something around these lines maybe? but im missing where to add the ONLINE API.

```
app.post('/create', (req, res) => {
    const position = req.body.position
    const name = req.body.name
    const alliance = req.body.alliance
    const points = req.body.points

    db.query("INSERT INTO stats (position, name, alliance, points) VALUES (?,?,?,?)",
        [position, name, alliance, points],
        (err, result) => {
            if (err) {
                console.log(err)
            } else {
                res.send("Values Inserted")
            }

        }
    );

});
```

Comment: Can you post what you have tried?

Comment: sure i just edited the post, i been thinking that adds inputs that you write on frontend page, maybe adapting that code to add the rest api information somewhere inside the code?

Answer (score 0):

It depends on the controller you will use and how you split your code. This is an implementation of mysql2 package

```
export class MySQLBackend {
  connection: mysql.Pool;
  constructor() {
    this.connection = mysql.createPool({
      host: "localhost",
      user: "root",
      port: 3306,
      password: config.mysqlPass,
      database: config.mysqlDb,
      waitForConnections: true,
      connectionLimit: 10,
      queueLimit: 0,
    });
    debugLog("conectado a mysql");
  }

  // eslint-disable-next-line @typescript-eslint/no-explicit-any
  execQuery(query: string): Promise<any> {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      this.connection.query(query, (error, results) => {
        if (error) {
          reject(error);
        }
        resolve(results);
      });
    });
  }
}
```

I run all commands with execQuery, so now an example.

```
async createOne({
    se_name,
    se_logo,
  }: Omit<StockExchange, "se_id">): Promise<MutationResult> {
    try {
      const data: MutateOneMysqlResult = await mysql.execQuery(
        `INSERT INTO bolsas
        (
          nombre,
          bolsa_logo
        )
        VALUES
        (
          '${se_name}',
          '${se_logo}'
        )`
      );
      return data
    } catch (error) {...}
}
```